# How to reorder numbering in INT column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a table `Customer`

```
name                 seq
-------------------- -----------
Johnny               1
Jack                 3
Jim                  4
```

Both `name` and `seq` are primary key. This is my expected result

```
name                 seq
-------------------- -----------
Johnny               1
Jack                 2
Jim                  3
```

Any idea how to achieve this? I tried using UPDATE along with ROW_NUMBER but it won't let me due to `num` is a primary key column.

Note: The new sequence must be ordered by `seq` (not `name`).

Comment: Do you mean you want to update the table data, or just select the values?

Comment: update the data

Comment: There is no prohibition on updating primary keys. Is it identity?

Comment: But why do you want to do this? It's generally a bad idea to renumber id's.

Comment: I assume you either have no related data or are going to tidy that too? If you have referential integrity properly set up, you may be able to use `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. If I were you, I'd use extreme care!

Comment: I understand it's generally bad idea to do this kind of thing, but this is not a side project and the table structure is designed this way from the start and changing the structure is too risky, so this kind of hacks is preferred

Comment: `name` and `seq` are primary keys.  That is a problem right there.  A table has only one primary key.  And if `seq` is unique, that is the right one.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I read it as name and seq together are the primary key, a composite one.

Comment: @jarlh . . . And given the question and sample data, that is silly.  The numeric value should be the primary key because it is unique and non-null.

Comment: The sample I provided is not a real structure used in production, I just made it simpler because nobody wants a table with tons of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update via a CTE

```
Declare @YourTable table (name varchar(25),seq int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('Johnny',1),
('Jack',  3),
('Jim',   4)

;with cte as (
    Select *
          ,RN = Row_Number() over (Order By Seq)
    From  @YourTable
)
Update cte Set Seq=RN

Select * from @YourTable
```

Returns

```
name    seq
Johnny  1
Jack    2
Jim     3
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Had to take a second look myself

Comment: The question also states "I tried using UPDATE along with ROW_NUMBER but it won't let me due to num is a primary key column"